# Crystal reports - get crosstab column value from different table

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have a crystal report based on xml data with a crosstab for displaying the main set of data that I want.

Some of the values that I need to display in the header are in a dictionary 'table' in the xml and I need to extract the value of a field where the name is e.g. 'CrossTabColumnName'.

I can do this in a subreport and use a shared variable to put it onto the main report, but it won't let me put it in the crosstab because it 'has to be evaluated later' - fine I get the idea behind this but how can I get this value into where I want it?

I just want to be able to say, for example: Select Value From DictionaryTable Where Name='CrossTabColumnName', and put that into a field I can use in the cross tab.

Comment: which section crosstab is placed and which section you want to display the variable.

Comment: cross tab is in the main report and I want to display it in one of the column headers. I have got round this now, but I could do with a better solution. Should I be putting the Crosstab in a subreport?